# On the Nilradical $N(R)$ of a noncommutative ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, ideals, noncommutative-algebra, nilpotence

I am doing some Noncommutative Algebra and I am studying the notion of the nilradical of a (not necessarily) commutative ring. More precisely:

Let $R$ be a ring with $1_R$. The **nilradical** $N(R)\subseteq R$ of $R$ is the sum of all nilpotent ideals of $R$. That is,
$$\boxed{N(R):=\sum\{ I\trianglelefteq R:\ I \text{ is a nilpotent ideal of } R\}\subseteq R}.$$
So, I have some questions:

1. I searched some books and on the internet but I didn't find this definition.  All the sources said that it is the set consisting of all nilpotent elements of $R$. Is there a reason for using this? And is there a kind of equivalence between them?
2. Does this definition mean that $N(R)$ is equal to $I_1+I_2+\dotsb+I_n+\dotsb \trianglelefteq R$, where $I_1,I_2,\dots,I_n,\dots\trianglelefteq R$ are all (possibly infinite) nilpotent two-sided ideals of $R$?
3. If the above are correct, we realise that $N(R)$ is a two-sided ideal of $R$. Now, in my notes,
   $$N(R) \subseteq \sum\{ I \underset{\ell}{\trianglelefteq} R:\ I \text{ is a nilpotent left ideal of } R\}.$$
   But I can not see why this happens.

*Thanks.*

Comment: For commutative rings, the nilradical is just the set of all nilpotent elements and it turns out that by the binomial theorem this is in fact an ideal. For non-commutative rings you don't have the binomial theorem and thus there's the question how to generalize the notion in the "correct" way. You can look this up in the (english) wikipedia article and there's also a discussion of the non-commutative case.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What about the other questions? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper nilradical $Nil^\ast(R)$ is defined to be the sum of *nil* ideals.

The lower nilradical $Nil_\ast(R)$ is defined to be the intersection of prime ideals of the ring.

In the context of Artinian rings, nil radicals are nilpotent, so the sum of all nilpotent ideals is again a nilpotent ideal, and this is sometimes referred to as the Wedderburn radical. But I'm not sure if anyone uses the sum of all nilpotent ideals outside this context.

We have $N(R)\subseteq Nil_\ast(R)\subseteq Nil^\ast(R)$, and I don't think the first two are always equal.

1. No, it is not the set of nilpotent elements. Take $M_2(F)$ for any field $F$, and $N(R)$ is the zero ideal, yet there are nilpotent elements.
2. Yes.
3. Every nilpotent ideal is a nilpotent left ideal.  So the set of nilpotent ideals is a subset of the set of nilpotent left ideals. Therefore the sum of the former is contained in the sum of the latter. There is nothing hard here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Yes, we used this definition out (at the beginning) out of the context of Artinian rings, where as you said nil and nilpotent ideals are the same. As for 1., I had a typo, check my update please.

Comment: @Chris Adapted.

Comment: A "stupid" question about 3. Is it because every (2-sided) ideal is a left ideal?

Comment: @chris yes, that is so.

Comment: Thank you very much.